# Trace which route is governing a particular controller endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to alter a particular routing in my code for an endpoint.  Basically, I want to just change this:

```
        public Event_model Get(int id)
        {
            return Event.GetEventById(id);
        }
```

To this:

```
        public Event_model Get(string id)
        {
            return Event.GetEventById(id);
        }
```

This should be easily done, but no matter how I alter my route for this endpoint in the `WebApiConfig.cs`, it has no affect on the controller.  SO, I can only assume some other route (out of the several I have) is governing this endpoint.

Is there a way to trace which route is governing a particular endpoint?

Comment: Please provide more info. At least the route config and the controller name

Comment: Phil Haack's Route Debugger might still work.  It was up to date as of July 2012.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/2.1.4

Comment: What do you mean by "it has no affect on the controller"?  What behavior are you expecting, what behavior are you seeing, and how are you testing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey--Thanks-I had high hopes for this as it sounded exactly like what I needed.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to work for WebAPI.

Comment: @TroyCarlson--What I mean is that, for example, I can add a letters only constraint to the route (e.g. `constraints: new {id= @"[A-Za-z]+"`) and yet setting the id parameter to an int in the controller still works.  So, again, it appears that the route I am working on is not what is actually governing my endpoint.

Comment: +1 for Route Debugger. Do keep in mind that it only shows how it routes a given request, not the other way around (like you need), but it helps to visualize it.

Comment: @TroyCarlson I believe in WebAPI base controller keeps reference to its execution context, and there I thought I saw information on which route is currently in context.  Maybe `ApiController.RequestContext.RouteData`??? If so, then you can see which specific route matched that activated your action, and thus identify the culprit...

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - Routes don't govern end points per say. They either match or not match. Once a route matches it passes down the pipe routedata, and then action selection takes place. You can absolutely have multiple routes hit the same method/endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You can look at:`this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Route` in your action method.

Specifically `this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Route.RouteTemplate`